# Convert command line cURL to PHP cURL

Tags: php, curl

I've never done any curl before so am in need of some help. I've tried to work this out from examples but cannot get my head around it!

I have a curl command that I can successfully run from a linux(ubuntu) command line that puts a file to a wiki through an api.

I would need to incorporate this curl command in a PHP script I'm building.

How can I translate this curl command so that it works in a PHP script?

```
curl -b cookie.txt -X PUT \
     --data-binary "@test.png" \
     -H "Content-Type: image/png" \    
     "http://hostname/@api/deki/pages/=TestPage/files/=test.png" \
     -0
```

cookie.txt contains the authentication but I don't have a problem putting this in clear text in the script as this will be run by me only.

@test.png must be a variable such as $filename

http://hostname/@api/deki/pages/=TestPage/files/= must be a variable such as $pageurl

Thanks for any help.

Comment: https://incarnate.github.io/curl-to-php/ looks like a good tool...

Answer (score 31, accepted):

a starting point:

```
<?php

$pageurl = "http://hostname/@api/deki/pages/=TestPage/files/=";
$filename = "test.png";

$theurl = $pageurl . $filename;

$ch = curl_init($theurl);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIE, ...); // -b
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, 'PUT'); // -X
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_BINARYTRANSFER, TRUE); // --data-binary
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, ['Content-Type: image/png']); // -H
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION, CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_0); // -0

...
?>
```

See also: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php

Answer (score 28):

You need ...

## curl-to-PHP : https://incarnate.github.io/curl-to-php/

*"Instantly convert curl commands to PHP code"*

Answer (score 15):

This is an autogenerated list of which [curl commandline options](https://curl.haxx.se/docs/manpage.html) might map onto which php CURLOPT_ constant:

| --arg | description | curl_setopt() |
| --- | --- | --- |
| `-a` `--append` | Append to target file when uploading | [`CURLOPT_FTPAPPEND`, `CURLOPT_APPEND`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php) |
| `--basic` | Use HTTP Basic Authentication | [`CURLAUTH_BASIC`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php) |
| `--cacert <file>` | CA certificate to verify peer against | [`CURLE_SSL_CACERT`, `CURLE_SSL_CACERT_BADFILE`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php) |
| `--capath <dir>` | CA directory to verify peer against | [`CURLOPT_CAPATH`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php) |
| `-E` `--cert <certificate[:password]>` | Client certificate file and password | [`CURLOPT_SSLCERT`, `CURLOPT_SSLCERTPASSWD`, `CURLOPT_SSLCERTTYPE`, `CURLE_SSL_CACERT`, `CURLE_SSL_CERTPROBLEM`, `CURLE_SSL_PEER_CERTIFICATE`, `CURLE_SSL_CACERT_BADFILE`, `CURLOPT_ISSUERCERT`, `CURLINFO_CERTINFO`, `CURLOPT_CERTINFO`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php) |
| `--connect-to <HOST1:PORT1:HOST2:PORT2>` | Connect to host | [`CURLOPT_CONNECT_TO`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php) |
| `-b` `--cookie <data>` | Send cookies from string/file | [`CURLOPT_COOKIE`, `CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE`, `CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR`, `CURLOPT_COOKIESESSION`, `CURL_LOCK_DATA_COOKIE`, `CURLINFO_COOKIELIST`, `CURLOPT_COOKIELIST`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php) |
| `--crlf` | Convert LF to CRLF in upload | [`CURLOPT_CRLF`, `CURLOPT_CRLFILE`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php) |
| `--crlfile <file>` | Get a CRL list in PEM format from the given file | [`CURLOPT_CRLFILE`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php) |
| `-d` `--data <data>` | HTTP POST data | [`CURLOPT_READDATA`, `CURL_LOCK_DATA_COOKIE`, `CURL_LOCK_DATA_DNS`, `CURL_LOCK_DATA_SSL_SESSION`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php) |
| `--delegation <LEVEL>` | GSS-API delegation permission | [`CURLGSSAPI_DELEGATION_FLAG`, `CURLGSSAPI_DELEGATION_POLICY_FLAG`, `CURLOPT_GSSAPI_DELEGATION`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php) |
| `--digest` | Use HTTP Digest Authentication | [`CURLAUTH_DIGEST`, `CURLAUTH_DIGEST_IE`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php) |
| `--dns-interface <interface>` | Interface to use for DNS requests | [`CURLOPT_DNS_INTERFACE`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php) |
| `--dns-servers <addresses>` | DNS server addrs to use | [`CURLOPT_DNS_SERVERS`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php) |
| `--engine <name>` | Crypto engine to use | [`CURLOPT_SSLENGINE`, `CURLOPT_SSLENGINE_DEFAULT`, `CURLE_SSL_ENGINE_NOTFOUND`, `CURLE_SSL_ENGINE_SETFAILED`, `CURLINFO_SSL_ENGINES`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php) |
| `-f` `--fail` | Fail silently (no output at all) on HTTP errors | [`CURLOPT_FAILONERROR`, `CURLE_FAILED_INIT`, `CURLE_FTP_PORT_FAILED`, `CURLE_HTTP_PORT_FAILED`, `CURLE_LDAP_SEARCH_FAILED`, `CURLE_SSL_ENGINE_SETFAILED`, `CURLE_FTP_SSL_FAILED`, `CURL_FNMATCHFUNC_FAIL`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php) |
| `-F` `--form <name=content>` | Specify multipart MIME data | [`CURLE_FTP_WEIRD_227_FORMAT`, `CURLE_MALFORMAT_USER`, `CURLE_URL_MALFORMAT`, `CURLE_URL_MALFORMAT_USER`, `CURLM_CALL_MULTI_PERFORM`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php) |
| `--ftp-account <data>` | Account data string | [`CURLOPT_FTP_ACCOUNT`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php) |
| `--ftp-alternative-to-user <command>` | String to replace USER [name] | [`CURLOPT_FTP_ALTERNATIVE_TO_USER`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php) |
| `-P` `--ftp-port <address>` | Use PORT instead of PASV | [`CURLE_FTP_PORT_FAILED`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php) |
| `--ftp-skip-pasv-ip` | Skip the IP address for PASV | [`CURLOPT_FTP_SKIP_PASV_IP`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php) |
| `--ftp-ssl-ccc` | Send CCC after authenticating | [`CURLOPT_FTP_SSL_CCC`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php) |
| `-G` `--get` | Put the post data in the URL and use GET | [`CURLOPT_HTTPGET`, `CURLE_FTP_CANT_GET_HOST`, `CURLE_FTP_COULDNT_GET_SIZE`, `CURL_RTSPREQ_GET_PARAMETER`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php) |
| `-I` `--head` | Show document info only | [`CURLOPT_HEADER`, `CURLOPT_HEADERFUNCTION`, `CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER`, `CURLOPT_WRITEHEADER`, `CURLINFO_HEADER_OUT`, `CURLINFO_HEADER_SIZE`, `CURLHEADER_SEPARATE`, `CURLHEADER_UNIFIED`, `CURLOPT_HEADEROPT`, `CURLOPT_PROXYHEADER`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php) |
| `-H` `--header <header/@file>` | Pass custom header(s) to server | [`CURLOPT_HEADER`, `CURLOPT_HEADERFUNCTION`, `CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER`, `CURLOPT_WRITEHEADER`, `CURLINFO_HEADER_OUT`, `CURLINFO_HEADER_SIZE`, `CURLHEADER_SEPARATE`, `CURLHEADER_UNIFIED`, `CURLOPT_HEADEROPT`, `CURLOPT_PROXYHEADER`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php) |
| `--http2` | Use HTTP 2 | [`CURLOPT_HTTP200ALIASES`, `CURL_VERSION_HTTP2`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php) |
| `--ignore-content-length` | Ignore the size of the remote resource | [`CURLOPT_IGNORE_CONTENT_LENGTH`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php) |
| `--interface <name>` | Use network INTERFACE (or address) | [`CURLOPT_INTERFACE`, `CURLOPT_DNS_INTERFACE`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php) |
| `-6` `--ipv6` | Resolve names to IPv6 addresses | [`CURL_VERSION_IPV6`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php) |
| `--key <key>` | Private key file name | [`CURLOPT_SSLKEY`, `CURLOPT_SSLKEYPASSWD`, `CURLOPT_SSLKEYTYPE`, `CURLE_SSL_PINNEDPUBKEYNOTMATCH`, `CURLOPT_SSH_PRIVATE_KEYFILE`, `CURLOPT_SSH_PUBLIC_KEYFILE`, `CURLOPT_SSH_HOST_PUBLIC_KEY_MD5`, `CURLOPT_KEYPASSWD`, `CURLSSH_AUTH_KEYBOARD`, `CURLSSH_AUTH_PUBLICKEY`, `CURLOPT_PINNEDPUBLICKEY`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php) |
| `--krb <level>` | Enable Kerberos with security | [`CURLOPT_KRB4LEVEL`, `CURLOPT_KRBLEVEL`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php) |
| `--local-port <num/range>` | Force use of RANGE for local port numbers | [`CURLINFO_LOCAL_PORT`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php) |
| `-L` `--location` | Follow redirects | [`CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php) |
| `--login-options <options>` | Server login options | [`CURLOPT_LOGIN_OPTIONS`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php) |
| `--mail-auth <address>` | Originator address of the original email | [`CURLOPT_MAIL_AUTH`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php) |
| `--mail-from <address>` | Mail from this address | [`CURLOPT_MAIL_FROM`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php) |
| `--mail-rcpt <address>` | Mail to this address | [`CURLOPT_MAIL_RCPT`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php) |
| `--negotiate` | Use HTTP Negotiate (SPNEGO) authentication | [`CURLAUTH_GSSNEGOTIATE`, `CURLAUTH_NEGOTIATE`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php) |
| `-n` `--netrc` | Must read .netrc for user name and password | [`CURLOPT_NETRC`, `CURL_NETRC_IGNORED`, `CURL_NETRC_OPTIONAL`, `CURL_NETRC_REQUIRED`, `CURLOPT_NETRC_FILE`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php) |
| `--netrc-file <filename>` | Specify FILE for netrc | [`CURLOPT_NETRC_FILE`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php) |
| `--netrc-optional` | Use either .netrc or URL | [`CURL_NETRC_OPTIONAL`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php) |
| `--noproxy <no-proxy-list>` | List of hosts which do not use proxy | [`CURLOPT_NOPROXY`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php) |
| `--ntlm` | Use HTTP NTLM authentication | [`CURLAUTH_NTLM`, `CURLAUTH_NTLM_WB`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php) |
| `--ntlm-wb` | Use HTTP NTLM authentication with winbind | [`CURLAUTH_NTLM_WB`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php) |
| `--oauth2-bearer <token>` | OAuth 2 Bearer Token | [`CURLOPT_XOAUTH2_BEARER`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php) |
| `--pass <phrase>` | Pass phrase for the private key | [`CURLOPT_SSLCERTPASSWD`, `CURLOPT_SSLKEYPASSWD`, `CURLE_BAD_PASSWORD_ENTERED`, `CURLE_FTP_USER_PASSWORD_INCORRECT`, `CURLE_FTP_WEIRD_PASS_REPLY`, `CURLFTPSSL_CCC_PASSIVE`, `CURLOPT_KEYPASSWD`, `CURLSSH_AUTH_PASSWORD`, `CURLOPT_PASSWORD`, `CURLOPT_PROXYPASSWORD`, `CURLOPT_TLSAUTH_PASSWORD`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php) |
| `--path-as-is` | Do not squash .. sequences in URL path | [`CURLOPT_PATH_AS_IS`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php) |
| `--pinnedpubkey <hashes>` | FILE/HASHES Public key to verify peer against | [`CURLE_SSL_PINNEDPUBKEYNOTMATCH`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php) |
| `--proto <protocols>` | Enable/disable PROTOCOLS | [`CURLE_UNSUPPORTED_PROTOCOL`, `CURLOPT_PROTOCOLS`, `CURLOPT_REDIR_PROTOCOLS`, `CURLPROTO_ALL`, `CURLPROTO_DICT`, `CURLPROTO_FILE`, `CURLPROTO_FTP`, `CURLPROTO_FTPS`, `CURLPROTO_HTTP`, `CURLPROTO_HTTPS`, `CURLPROTO_LDAP`, `CURLPROTO_LDAPS`, `CURLPROTO_SCP`, `CURLPROTO_SFTP`, `CURLPROTO_TELNET`, `CURLPROTO_TFTP`, `CURLPROTO_IMAP`, `CURLPROTO_IMAPS`, `CURLPROTO_POP3`, `CURLPROTO_POP3S`, `CURLPROTO_RTSP`, `CURLPROTO_SMTP`, `CURLPROTO_SMTPS`, `CURLPROTO_RTMP`, `CURLPROTO_RTMPE`, `CURLPROTO_RTMPS`, `CURLPROTO_RTMPT`, `CURLPROTO_RTMPTE`, `CURLPROTO_RTMPTS`, `CURLPROTO_GOPHER`, `CURLPROTO_SMB`, `CURLPROTO_SMBS`, `CURLOPT_DEFAULT_PROTOCOL`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php) |
| `--proxy-service-name <name>` | SPNEGO proxy service name | [`CURLOPT_PROXY_SERVICE_NAME`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php) |
| `-p` `--proxytunnel` | Operate through an HTTP proxy tunnel (using CONNECT) | [`CURLOPT_HTTPPROXYTUNNEL`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php) |
| `--pubkey <key>` | SSH Public key file name | [`CURLE_SSL_PINNEDPUBKEYNOTMATCH`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php) |
| `-Q` `--quote` | Send command(s) to server before transfer | [`CURLOPT_POSTQUOTE`, `CURLOPT_PREQUOTE`, `CURLOPT_QUOTE`, `CURLE_FTP_QUOTE_ERROR`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php) |
| `--random-file <file>` | File for reading random data from | [`CURLOPT_RANDOM_FILE`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php) |
| `-r` `--range <range>` | Retrieve only the bytes within RANGE | [`CURLOPT_RANGE`, `CURLE_HTTP_RANGE_ERROR`, `CURLOPT_LOCALPORTRANGE`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php) |
| `-e` `--referer <URL>` | Referrer URL | [`CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER`, `CURLOPT_REFERER`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php) |
| `-X` `--request <command>` | Specify request command to use | [`CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST`, `CURLINFO_REQUEST_SIZE`, `CURLOPT_RTSP_REQUEST`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php) |
| `--resolve <host:port:address[,address]...>` | Resolve the host+port to this address | [`CURLE_COULDNT_RESOLVE_HOST`, `CURLE_COULDNT_RESOLVE_PROXY`, `CURLOPT_IPRESOLVE`, `CURL_IPRESOLVE_V4`, `CURL_IPRESOLVE_V6`, `CURL_IPRESOLVE_WHATEVER`, `CURLOPT_RESOLVE`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php) |
| `--retry <num>` | Retry request if transient problems occur | [`CURLFTP_CREATE_DIR_RETRY`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php) |
| `--sasl-ir` | Enable initial response in SASL authentication | [`CURLOPT_SASL_IR`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php) |
| `--service-name <name>` | SPNEGO service name | [`CURLOPT_PROXY_SERVICE_NAME`, `CURLOPT_SERVICE_NAME`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php) |
| `--socks4 <host[:port]>` | SOCKS4 proxy on given host + port | [`CURLPROXY_SOCKS4`, `CURLPROXY_SOCKS4A`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php) |
| `--socks4a <host[:port]>` | SOCKS4a proxy on given host + port | [`CURLPROXY_SOCKS4A`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php) |
| `--socks5 <host[:port]>` | SOCKS5 proxy on given host + port | [`CURLPROXY_SOCKS5`, `CURLPROXY_SOCKS5_HOSTNAME`, `CURLOPT_SOCKS5_GSSAPI_NEC`, `CURLOPT_SOCKS5_GSSAPI_SERVICE`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php) |
| `--socks5-gssapi` | Enable GSS-API auth for SOCKS5 proxies | [`CURLOPT_SOCKS5_GSSAPI_NEC`, `CURLOPT_SOCKS5_GSSAPI_SERVICE`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php) |
| `--socks5-gssapi-nec` | Compatibility with NEC SOCKS5 server | [`CURLOPT_SOCKS5_GSSAPI_NEC`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php) |
| `--socks5-gssapi-service <name>` | SOCKS5 proxy service name for GSS-API | [`CURLOPT_SOCKS5_GSSAPI_SERVICE`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php) |
| `--socks5-hostname <host[:port]>` | SOCKS5 proxy, pass host name to proxy | [`CURLPROXY_SOCKS5_HOSTNAME`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php) |
| `-Y` `--speed-limit <speed>` | Stop transfers slower than this | [`CURLOPT_LOW_SPEED_LIMIT`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php) |
| `-y` `--speed-time <seconds>` | Trigger 'speed-limit' abort after this time | [`CURLOPT_LOW_SPEED_TIME`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php) |
| `--ssl` | Try SSL/TLS | [`CURLOPT_SSLCERT`, `CURLOPT_SSLCERTPASSWD`, `CURLOPT_SSLCERTTYPE`, `CURLOPT_SSLENGINE`, `CURLOPT_SSLENGINE_DEFAULT`, `CURLOPT_SSLKEY`, `CURLOPT_SSLKEYPASSWD`, `CURLOPT_SSLKEYTYPE`, `CURLOPT_SSLVERSION`, `CURLOPT_SSL_CIPHER_LIST`, `CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST`, `CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER`, `CURLE_SSL_CACERT`, `CURLE_SSL_CERTPROBLEM`, `CURLE_SSL_CIPHER`, `CURLE_SSL_CONNECT_ERROR`, `CURLE_SSL_ENGINE_NOTFOUND`, `CURLE_SSL_ENGINE_SETFAILED`, `CURLE_SSL_PEER_CERTIFICATE`, `CURLE_SSL_PINNEDPUBKEYNOTMATCH`, `CURLINFO_SSL_VERIFYRESULT`, `CURL_LOCK_DATA_SSL_SESSION`, `CURL_SSLVERSION_DEFAULT`, `CURL_SSLVERSION_SSLv2`, `CURL_SSLVERSION_SSLv3`, `CURL_SSLVERSION_TLSv1`, `CURL_VERSION_SSL`, `CURLE_FTP_SSL_FAILED`, `CURLFTPSSL_ALL`, `CURLFTPSSL_CONTROL`, `CURLFTPSSL_NONE`, `CURLFTPSSL_TRY`, `CURLOPT_FTP_SSL`, `CURLFTPAUTH_SSL`, `CURLOPT_FTPSSLAUTH`, `CURLINFO_SSL_ENGINES`, `CURLE_SSL_CACERT_BADFILE`, `CURLOPT_SSL_SESSIONID_CACHE`, `CURLOPT_FTP_SSL_CCC`, `CURLFTPSSL_CCC_ACTIVE`, `CURLFTPSSL_CCC_NONE`, `CURLFTPSSL_CCC_PASSIVE`, `CURLOPT_USE_SSL`, `CURLUSESSL_ALL`, `CURLUSESSL_CONTROL`, `CURLUSESSL_NONE`, `CURLUSESSL_TRY`, `CURLOPT_SSL_OPTIONS`, `CURLSSLOPT_ALLOW_BEAST`, `CURL_SSLVERSION_TLSv1_0`, `CURL_SSLVERSION_TLSv1_1`, `CURL_SSLVERSION_TLSv1_2`, `CURLOPT_SSL_ENABLE_ALPN`, `CURLOPT_SSL_ENABLE_NPN`, `CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYSTATUS`, `CURLOPT_SSL_FALSESTART`, `CURLSSLOPT_NO_REVOKE`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php) |
| `-2` `--sslv2` | Use SSLv2 | [`CURL_SSLVERSION_SSLv2`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php) |
| `-3` `--sslv3` | Use SSLv3 | [`CURL_SSLVERSION_SSLv3`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php) |
| `--stderr` | Where to redirect stderr | [`CURLOPT_STDERR`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php) |
| `--tcp-fastopen` | Use TCP Fast Open | [`CURLOPT_TCP_FASTOPEN`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php) |
| `--tcp-nodelay` | Use the TCP_NODELAY option | [`CURLOPT_TCP_NODELAY`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php) |
| `-t` `--telnet-option <opt=val>` | Set telnet option | [`CURLE_TELNET_OPTION_SYNTAX`, `CURLE_UNKNOWN_TELNET_OPTION`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php) |
| `--tftp-blksize <value>` | Set TFTP BLKSIZE option | [`CURLOPT_TFTP_BLKSIZE`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php) |
| `--tftp-no-options` | Do not send any TFTP options | [`CURLOPT_TFTP_NO_OPTIONS`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php) |
| `-1` `--tlsv1` | Use TLSv1.0 or greater | [`CURL_SSLVERSION_TLSv1`, `CURL_SSLVERSION_TLSv1_0`, `CURL_SSLVERSION_TLSv1_1`, `CURL_SSLVERSION_TLSv1_2`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php) |
| `--unix-socket <path>` | Connect through this Unix domain socket | [`CURLOPT_UNIX_SOCKET_PATH`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php) |
| `--url <url>` | URL to work with | [`CURLOPT_URL`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php) |
| `-u` `--user <user:password>` | Server user and password | [`CURLOPT_PROXYUSERPWD`, `CURLOPT_USERAGENT`, `CURLOPT_USERPWD`, `CURLE_FTP_USER_PASSWORD_INCORRECT`, `CURLE_FTP_WEIRD_USER_REPLY`, `CURLE_MALFORMAT_USER`, `CURLE_URL_MALFORMAT_USER`, `CURLOPT_FTP_ALTERNATIVE_TO_USER`, `CURLOPT_PROXYUSERNAME`, `CURLOPT_USERNAME`, `CURLOPT_TLSAUTH_USERNAME`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php) |
| `-v` `--verbose` | Make the operation more talkative | [`CURLOPT_VERBOSE`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php) |
| `-V` `--version` | Show version number and quit | [`CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION`, `CURLOPT_SSLVERSION`, `CURLVERSION_NOW`, `CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_0`, `CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1`, `CURL_HTTP_VERSION_NONE`, `CURL_SSLVERSION_DEFAULT`, `CURL_SSLVERSION_SSLv2`, `CURL_SSLVERSION_SSLv3`, `CURL_SSLVERSION_TLSv1`, `CURL_VERSION_IPV6`, `CURL_VERSION_KERBEROS4`, `CURL_VERSION_LIBZ`, `CURL_VERSION_SSL`, `CURL_HTTP_VERSION_2_0`, `CURL_VERSION_HTTP2`, `CURL_SSLVERSION_TLSv1_0`, `CURL_SSLVERSION_TLSv1_1`, `CURL_SSLVERSION_TLSv1_2`, `CURL_HTTP_VERSION_2`, `CURL_HTTP_VERSION_2TLS`, `CURL_HTTP_VERSION_2_PRIOR_KNOWLEDGE`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php) |

Note that this only lists somewhat exact matches of --long options to similarly named CURLOPT_ constants. But it should give you enough hints on how to compare the  [`curl --help`](https://curl.haxx.se/docs/manpage.html) output and the PHP curl_setopt() list.

Answer (score 12):

Whicvhever cURL you have in command line, you can convert it to PHP with this tool:

```
https://incarnate.github.io/curl-to-php/
```

It helped me after long long hours of searching for a solution! Hope it will help you out too! Your solution is this:

```
// Generated by curl-to-PHP: http://incarnate.github.io/curl-to-php/
$ch = curl_init();

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "http://hostname/@api/deki/pages/=TestPage/files/=test.png");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
$post = array(
    "file" => "@" .realpath("test.png")
);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "PUT");


$headers = array();
$headers[] = "Content-Type: image/png";
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);

$result = curl_exec($ch);
if (curl_errno($ch)) {
    echo 'Error:' . curl_error($ch);
}
curl_close ($ch);
```

Comment: Thank you very much for this : https://incarnate.github.io/curl-to-php/ , I spent almost a day to figure out how to set header properly

Comment: I am glad it helped. Just a crazy thought - tou can also for example upvote my answer and comments ;)

Answer (score 7):

Try this:

```
$cmd='curl -b cookie.txt -X PUT \
     --data-binary "@test.png" \
     -H "Content-Type: image/png" \    
     "http://hostname/@api/deki/pages/=TestPage/files/=test.png" \
     -0';
exec($cmd,$result);
```

Comment: I posted a duplicate question like this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38064372/curl-command-in-php. This solution is pretty nice and wondering what if I have some `vars` in the curl command like `curl -b $TEST -X PUT --data-binary $CHECK` and so on. Would this still work?

Comment: @PratikJaiswal of course it will work. But you have to use double quotes instead of single quotes. that means you have replace starting and ending ' with " and all of " in your code with '

Comment: Don't some servers have ```exec``` disabled for security reasons?

Answer (score 2):

the --libcurl option was added for this purpose, even though it makes a C program I think it should be fairly easy to translate to PHP

Answer (score 2):

Using MYYN's answer as a starting point, and [this page](http://dtbaker.com.au/random-bits/uploading-a-file-using-curl-in-php.html) as a reference on how to send POST data using PHP cURL, here is my suggestion (I am working on something very similar at the moment):

```
<?php

$pageurl = "http://hostname/@api/deki/pages/=TestPage/files/=";
$filename = "test.png";

$theurl = $pageurl.$filename;

$ch = curl_init($theurl);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIE, ...); // -b
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, 'PUT'); // -X
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_BINARYTRANSFER, TRUE); // --data-binary
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, ['Content-Type: image/png']); // -H
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION, CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_0); // -0

$post = array("$filename"=>"@$filename");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post); 
$response = curl_exec($ch);
?>
```

You can probably optimize the many curl_setopts with the use of a curl_setopt_array() call if you desire.

Answer (score 1):

Better this. In one line.

```
$cmd='curl -b cookie.txt -X PUT --data-binary "@test.png" -H "Content-Type: image/png" "http://hostname/@api/deki/pages/=TestPage/files/=test.png" -0';
exec($cmd,$result);
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [curlconverter.com/php/](https://curlconverter.com/php/), it will convert your curl command into

```php
<?php
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://hostname/@api/deki/pages/=TestPage/files/=test.png');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, 'PUT');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, [
    'Content-Type' => 'image/png',
]);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, file_get_contents('test.png'));

$response = curl_exec($ch);

curl_close($ch);
```