# CLI cURL to PHP cURL

Tags: php, curl, command-line-interface

I am working on a fast caching system to work with a PHP framework. Basicly, all static pages don't need to be loaded with framework, so I wanted to use CURL. For the command line it works very fast:

```
$ curl http://www.example.com/en/terms-of-use.html > web/cache/en/terms-of-use.html
```

My current solution is getting the file data with curl, open/create a file and put all the data in that. I'm not very familiar with curl, but there should be a faster way I think if the CLI version is very short.

Comment: are you building a reverse proxy ?

Comment: It doesn't make sense that curl is faster than visiting the webpage in any other browser .. I assume you are talking about loading the html statically to a file and just displaying that file.  Using curl on the fly should not be any faster.

Comment: Maybe I formulated it wrong. And it is kind of like reverse proxy that @arnaud576875 said. I save the result once to a static HTML page and give that to the user. No framework to load for the user should really make a difference.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Convert command line cURL to PHP cURL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1939609/convert-command-line-curl-to-php-curl)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if it's faster, I still need to do some benchmarks, but it is a lot shorter to write.

```
<?php
    if(!copy('http://www.website.com/en/homepage.html', 'web/cache/en/homepage.html'))
    {
        // Notify someone
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this in one of 2 ways:

Use PHP's system / process function calls....

```
    $page = system("curl http://www.example.com/en/terms-of-use.html");
    print "<pre>";
    print_r($page);
    print "</pre>";
```

or you can use the native curl PHP libraries

```
    <?php
      $url = "http://www.example.com/en/terms-of-use.html";
      print $url;
      $ch = curl_init($url);
      if(!$ch)
      {
        $errstr = "Could not connect to server.";
      }
      curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
      $page = curl_exec($ch);
      print "<pre>";
      print_r($page);
      print "</pre>";
    ?>
```