# How to convert a command line cUrl to PHP cUrl

Tags: php, curl

I was trying to publish messages from PHP and I need to convert the following command into a PHP cURL:

```
  curl -X PUT --data-binary "Hello World" http://eclipse.mqttbridge.com/test
```

No matter what I try i cannot get it going. I tried `curl_exec` and `exec` commands but no results. How do you convert this command into PHP cUrl, or at least execute from `exec` command?

Thanks!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Convert command line cURL to PHP cURL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1939609/convert-command-line-curl-to-php-curl)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
    $data = "Hello World";
    $ch = curl_init('http://eclipse.mqttbridge.com/test');

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "PUT");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);

    $response = curl_exec($ch);
```