# How to scrape data from asmx web service generated page

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, web-services

I have been searching on the net but found nothing useful. I need to update my product prices from the supplier website automatically. I wanted to scrape information from category page for all product at once.

I used simple html dom method to get data. When I used tags to retrieve prices wihch I got from firefox firebug extension, it printed nothing. I tried to print all links in that category page and no product link in them. When I looked at the source code of the site with right click on page, I saw no code related to products. the div is empty like;

```
<div class=coll-2 fleft> </div>
```

But it was full of code in firebug extension. Then I saw that a js file have this codes;

```
function GetProductListHeader() {
var startPage = GetStartPage();
if (pageName == 'kategori' || pageName == 'reyon') {
    var BrandList = GetQueryStringByName("Brand");
    var ColorList = GetQueryStringByName("Color");
    var PropList = GetQueryStringByName("propid");
    var ItemDim1CodeList = GetQueryStringByName("vcode");
    var QPrice = GetQueryStringByName("price");
    var cFilter = GetQueryStringByName("cfilter");

    var parametre = { PageName: pageName, pUrl: PageUrl, BrandList: BrandList, ColorList: ColorList, ItemDim1CodeList: ItemDim1CodeList, PropList: PropList, QPrice: QPrice, cFilter: cFilter, startPage: startPage };
    $.ajax(
        {
            url: '/WS/wsProduct.asmx/GetProductListHeader',
            type: 'POST',
            processData: false,
            contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
            data: JSON.stringify(parametre),
            dataType: 'json',
            async: true
        })
        .done(function (e) {
            if (e.d != "") {  
                $('.coll-2').html(e.d);
                GetProductList(startPage);
            }
        })
}
}
```

Is there any way to get this datas with php?

Thank you.

Edit: I tried to setup the curl code after getting it from chrome network, I used below script;

```
$html = 'curl "http://bebekbayi.com/WS/wsProduct.asmx/GetProductList" \ 
    -H "Cookie: ASP.NET_SessionId=wy5hyt1bujcrdka2hpbp2wnm; _gat=1; _ga=GA1.2.1204447549.1447830812" \ 
    -H "Origin: http://bebekbayi.com" \ 
    -H "Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate" \ 
    -H "Accept-Language: tr-TR,tr;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.6,en;q=0.4" \ 
    -H "User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/46.0.2490.86 Safari/537.36" \ 
    -H "Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8" \ 
    -H "Accept: application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01" \ 
    -H "Cache-Control: max-age=0" \ 
    -H "X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest" \ 
    -H "Connection: keep-alive" \ 
    -H "Referer: http://bebekbayi.com/kategori/bakim-cantalari" 
    --data-binary "{""PageName"":""kategori"",""pUrl"":""bakim-cantalari"",""pIndex"":1,""BrandList"":"""",""ColorList"":"""",""ItemDim1CodeList"":"""",""PropList"":"""",""QPrice"":"""",""cFilter"":""""}" --compressed';
exec($html,$result);
   foreach($result as $res){

       echo $res . '<br>'; 
   }
```

It returned;
[InvalidOperationException: Request format is unrecognized for URL unexpectedly ending in '/GetProductList'.]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your task is now getting easier that you directly get the data source.

What you can do is you can get the full URL of the webservice and make PHP CURL Call.

So you will get the response, Generally it will be in the XML but it will depend on how this webservice is written.

here is the code.

```
$html = "curl 'http://bebekbayi.com/WS/wsProduct.asmx/GetProductList' -H 'Origin: http://bebekbayi.com' -H 'Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate' -H 'Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8' -H 'User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_11_0) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/46.0.2490.86 Safari/537.36' -H 'Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8' -H 'Accept: application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01' -H 'Referer: http://bebekbayi.com/reyon/Anne' -H 'X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest' -H 'Connection: keep-alive' --data-binary '{\"PageName\":\"reyon\",\"pUrl\":\"Anne\",\"pIndex\":1,\"BrandList\":\"\",\"ColorList\":\"\",\"ItemDim1CodeList\":\"\",\"PropList\":\"\",\"QPrice\":\"\",\"cFilter\":\"\"}' --compressed";
exec($html,$result);
$obj =  json_decode(implode("",$result) , true);
print_R($obj);exit;
exit;
```

Comment: I am not familiar with asmx web services and don't know how to setup this url. How can I get this url?

Comment: You may got it from the chrome network activity !  or just provide full URL then wr may help you

Comment: http://bebekbayi.com/reyon/Anne is the site, Yeditepe.Master.js is the script file.

Comment: Here you go. Check the attached screenshot and you will get it what i mean by Chrome Network activity.  >> http://prntscr.com/94180p

Comment: I got what you mean. I can copy as cURL now. It is a quite long term. One more thing to ask: how to use this code in cURL? Thank you.

Comment: may be you can use some help from stackoverflow itself ;)  . http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1939609/convert-command-line-curl-to-php-curl
Don't forget to accept my answer

Comment: Thank you for your efforts, I tried something and edited the message. The code returned an error.

Comment: i have updated the answer and i think it should work for you now.

Comment: Thank you very much. If you could show me how to find the each product link. I would appreciate it.