# Confused about command line cURL to PHP script call

Tags: php, curl, paypal

I am trying to convert this cURL command line call to a PHP script. I've read many articles on it , and have tried several options but none were able to return a result. Here's the command line call:

```
curl -v https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/oauth2/token \
-H "Accept: application/json" \
-H "Accept-Language: en_US" \
-u "EOJ2S-Z6OoN_le_KS1d75wsZ6y0SFdVsY9183IvxFyZp
:EClusMEUk8e9ihI7ZdVLF5cZ6y0SFdVsY9183IvxFyZp" \
-d "grant_type=client_credentials"
```

Here is what I have tried so far:

```
$data = "grant_type=client_credentials";
$url = "https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/oauth2/token";
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL,$url);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_HEADER,true);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array("Accept:application/json","Accept-     Language:en_US"));

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, "[$idclient]:[$sekret]");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);

$result = curl_exec($ch);

curl_close($ch);

echo $result;
var_dump($result);
```

Please help me in converting it to a PHP script call.

thank you

Comment: Can you add what you've tried in PHP even if it isn't working?

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/ref.curl.php

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Convert command line cURL to PHP cURL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1939609/convert-command-line-curl-to-php-curl)

Comment: Okay @mkaatman I've added what I have been trying so far. Thanks for your advice.

Answer (score 1):

```
$url = 'https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/oauth2/token';

$header_array = array(
    'Accept: application/json',
    'Accept-Language: en_US',
);

$username = 'EOJ2S-Z6OoN_le_KS1d75wsZ6y0SFdVsY9183IvxFyZp';
$password = 'EClusMEUk8e9ihI7ZdVLF5cZ6y0SFdVsY9183IvxFyZp';

$data_string = 'grant_type=client_credentials';

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 5);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 5);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $header_array);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data_string); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, $username . ":" . $password);  
$data = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);

var_dump($data);
```

Comment: But perhaps you should think about using the PayPal PHP SDK?

Comment: Associative arrays won't work with `CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER`. The array should look like this: 
`['Accept: application/json', 'Accept-Language: en_US']`