# Curl command in PHP

Tags: php, curl, command-line

I have a following `curl` command that works `fine on mac command line/terminal`:

```
curl -X POST http://build:f9280f220bf7b75396f83a0@mobile-jenkins.domain.com:8080/job/qa-trserver-git/build
--data-urlencode json='{"parameter": [{"name":"POST_RESULTS", "value":"true"}, {"name":"RUN_ID", "value":"744"}, {"name":"PLAN", "value":"SamplePlan"}]}'
```

How to use this `curl command in php` program?

Something I can think of:

```
<?php

 curl -X POST http://build:f9280f220bf7b75396f83a0@mobile-jenkins.domain.com:8080/job/qa-trserver-git/build
--data-urlencode json='{"parameter": [{"name":"POST_RESULTS", "value":"true"}, {"name":"RUN_ID", "value":"744"}, {"name":"PLAN", "value":"SamplePlan"}]}'

?>
```

An example with the input will be helpful.

Comment: Thanks for pointing this as duplicate. I think `$cmd='curl....'`
`exec($cmd,$result);` should work for me. How about if I have some vars in the curl command?. Not sure if I can make a comment on the post that you are pointing to.

Comment: @Dagon any thoughts on my comment above ?