# Transform Curl in php

Tags: php, curl

I've got this code in cURL. I'd like to transform or execute it in PHP.

```
curl -X POST -H "auth_id: {{market_id}}" -H "auth_token: {{auth_token}}" -H "Content-Type: multipart/form-data;" -F "campaign_slug={{campaign_slug}}" -F "csv=@{{file.csv}}" 'https://{{market_subdomain}}.co-buying.com/api/potential_campaign_signups/upload'
```

Could you please tell me how to do it ?

Thank you 
Bastien

Comment: Please believe to power of search.

Comment: This question violates the guidelines as it qualifies as too broad.

Answer (score -1):

You can use [curl-to-php](https://incarnate.github.io/curl-to-php/)

```
$ch = curl_init();

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://{{market_subdomain}}.co-buying.com/api/potential_campaign_signups/upload");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);

$headers = array();
$headers[] = "Auth_id: {{market_id}}";
$headers[] = "Auth_token: {{auth_token}}";
$headers[] = "Content-Type: multipart/form-data;";
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);

$result = curl_exec($ch);
if (curl_errno($ch)) {
    echo 'Error:' . curl_error($ch);
}
curl_close ($ch);
```

Answer (score -2):

You can use some online converters. Like
https://incarnate.github.io/curl-to-php/
To write by yourself this url might a guide for you;
http://code.stephenmorley.org/php/sending-files-using-curl/

also please check for full [curl parameters](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php) coverage

if you can't success, you might want to try

```
exec($curlCommand,$result);
```

Also please read exec [documentation](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php)

Comment: Thank you but I've already tried. And it does not take in consideration all the information like the csv file for the post.

Comment: then please check this one out: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1939609/convert-command-line-curl-to-php-curl